# Unable to install Scoop in Windows 7 under proxy settings, giving exception?

Tags: powershell, newscoop

I'm trying to install Scoop in Windows 7 with Windows PowerShell in my office, but it is giving below error:

> Exception calling "Download String" with "1" argument(s):"The remote server returned and error :(407) proxy authentication is required."

I've entered the following commands in a PowerShell console:

```
PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust.
Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks described
in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/
?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
PS> iex (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

Comment: Sharing the code with us would be helpful!

Comment: Apparently you're connecting through a proxy that requires authentication, which your code doesn't provide.

Comment: Please check the question ,i've added more details about steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PsGet through a Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8905013/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that your default browser can go to https://get.scoop.sh, which means you have effective proxy settings to access the site.
2. Enter the followings:

   ```
   PS> $wc = new-object net.webclient
   PS> $wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
   PS> iex $wc.downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
   ```